# Securely handling refresh token on a Vue application

Tags: security, vue.js, cookies, axios, refresh-token

I have a server backend that provides an access token and a refresh token when a user login is successful, and I want to store them somehow in the client's browser. For the access token, since it's short lived, I can store it in the browser's local storage, without having to worry too much. But for the refresh token, I'd like to set a more secure flow.

I've read this article fragment: [Sending refresh token as an HttpOnly cookie](https://blog.hasura.io/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/#refresh_token_login), and using a cookie sounds like a safer approach to me, obviously not perfect though, so what I want to do is send the refresh token as a **HttpOnly cookie** to the Vue application.

So after logging in, for example, I'd like the server to set up that cookie and make the client include it with every request sent to the backend (is that how it should work?).

The problem I think I have, correct me if I am wrong please, is that since only the browser and not the javascript has access to that HttpOnly cookie, I can't make the library I use to make the requests (axios) to send the set refresh token alongside its future requests as a HttpOnly cookie as well.

How can I make that flow properly? Did I misunderstand something about how these cookies work?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: As I understood it is not secure to store secret data in the browser at all, though it is done often. You can only reduce the risk that they are stolen by using HttpOnly-flags. So unfortunately there is no easy solution. Some web providers start to manage credential tokens only in the backends and work with sessions in the frontend. Unfortunately I have no example how to do that.